# Hacer una lista en python de una funcion fibonacci

Tags: python, fibonacci

Quería hacer una lista de una función Fibonacci multiplicativa que te pide el límite pero no sé cómo agregarla a una lista.
Le paso la función como parámetros pero no sale nada.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 1,2
    count = 0
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a * b
        count += 1
m = int(input("Ingresa límite máximo de la sucesión: "))     
fib(m)
    
def insertarNumerosLista(lista):
    numeros = [fib]
    numeros.append(fib)
    print(numeros)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar una lista se utiliza el método `append()`. Modificando tu código quedaría así:

```
def fib(n):
    result = [] # creando e inicializando la lista vacia
    a, b = 1, 2
    count = 0
    while a < n:
        result.append(a) # agregandolo a la lista
        a, b = b, a * b
        count += 1
    return result # retorna la lista con el resultado
```

Para más información sobre como utilizar las listas te recomiendo [esta página en español](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/listas-python/) que esta bastante buena

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonnacci(k):
    x =[1]*k
    i = 2
    while (i<k):
        x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2]
        i+=1
    return(x)

n = 0
f = []
while(n<=0):
    n = int(input('Entra el número de términos = '))
f = fibonnacci(n)
print(f)
```

Comment: La sucesión de Fibonacci que pretende hacer el OP es multiplicativa. Tú estás haciendo la versión aditiva clásica.

Comment: Hola mitus, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, aparte de lo que te comenta Jorge, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que la edites, a fin de adaptarla a la pregunta y las reglas del sitio, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Si deseas fusionar tus cuentas avisa así le podemos decir a algún moderador.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que separes la creación de la lista del resto de interacciones con el usuario.

Una sucesión de fibonacci multiplicativa se puede crear como una función generadora:

```py
def fib():
    a, b = 1, 2
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a*b
```

Para imprimir los primeros 10 elementos podemos usar la función `enumerate()` para obtener el orden de los elementos a medida que se calculan:

```py
for i, n in enumerate(fib()):
    if i >= 10:
        break
    print(f"fib({i}) = {n}")
```

De forma similar, podemos sacar elementos hasta un límite:

```py
max_n = int(input("Ingresa límite máximo de la sucesión: "))

for i, n in enumerate(fib()):
    if n >= max_n:
        break
    print(f"fib({i}) = {n}")
```

Si en lugar de imprimir los elementos queremos crear una lista, se puede hacer de este modo:

```py
result = []

for i, n in enumerate(fib()):
    if n >= max_n:
        break
    result.append(n)
```

Con un algo de conocimiento de *programación funcional* podemos mejorar el código usando el módulo [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). Con la función `takewhile` obtenemos los elementos de `fib()` hasta llegar al límite fijado:

```py
from itertools import takewhile

result = takewhile(lambda n: n <= max_n, fib())
result = list(result)
```

Por último, podemos hacer una versión más concisa integrando el límite en la función generadora de este modo:

```py
from collections.abc import Generator

def fib(max_n: int) -> Generator[int]:
    a, b = 1, 2
    while a <= max_n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a*b

max_n = int(input("Ingresa límite máximo de la sucesión: "))

result = list(fib(max_n))
```